# Retrieving material/colors/texture information from 3MF file

Tags: file-format

I’m trying to retrieve *visual* information about geometry, like textures, materials, colors and so on. I really don’t get how I’m supposed to traverse the resources and deduce their type. Each time I try that I end up with nothing (all returned pointers are null). I’m trying with [this file](https://github.com/3MFConsortium/3mf-samples/blob/master/materials/dodeca_chain_loop_color.3mf).

Plus, I don’t understand in the specs how I’m supposed to retrieve *indexed* information (in triangles for instance).

Comment: I can't even open most of the files in that directory in my archive manager. Some error occurs.